# Google Analytics: Exclude URL Query Parameters when using URL rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, google-analytics

I need to exclude some parameters to aggregate properly the pages of my website. I know there is "Exclude URL Query Parameters" and that's OK.

The problem  is when I use the URL rewrite. [Example](https://www.mysite.com/fbphoto/KUU1S5UFHDTOJP7T).

I have tried with a custom filter for renaming URLs, but it seems to be ignored. 
Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Please, see this screenshot:
[image: Filter Information]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt any of your URIs start with "fbphoto" (^fbphoto).  "/fbphoto" is more likely  (^/fbphoto)

If the intent is to rewrite all photo URLs with /fbphoto/, here's the syntax to use:

```
Search String:
^/fbphoto.*

Replace String:
/fbphoto/
```

Comment: This is a simple url rewrite. /fbphoto/123456 is like /fbphoto.php?photo_id=123456 every photo has a different entry so unless I rename them properly I will have hundreds of entries that actually point always to the same page. Just displaying a different photo. I hope my explaination makes sense